# how to make <a> href to have an "already clicked" style

Tags: html, css

I have a href,

is there any property to make it seen as clicked already?

(no css or js please)

Comment: Why don't you want to use css?

Comment: No way to do this without CSS. But really, if you have no CSS, the default should already do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this without CSS, thats exactly what is for...

Comment: what else do you expect other than css and js ?

Comment: what do you mean "seen" as already clicked? visually/style? programatically (an attribute)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `:visited`.

```
a:visited {

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use the `:visited` pseudo-class.

```
a:visited {
 color:#f00;
}
```

Read about it more in [the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3avisited) or in the [CSS Selectors Level 3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited).